# Accessing specific element of data-ri/data-row with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium in Java and I am learning Selenium to run simple tests. The test I am doing is to:

1. Open Firefox
2. Open Google
3. Go on Images and search Google
4. Click the second image

I noticed on google images they have under the div they have `data-ri` and `data-row`, so for example the first row is `data-row=0`, and the second element is `data-ri=1`, and the class is `rg_di`. How would I write a code in Java using Selenium to get the second element from the image search. I was thinking of using Xpath but I got confused.

EDIT (Forgot to post the code I had before):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.ca");

        System.out.println("Page title: " + driver.getTitle());
        String title = driver.getTitle();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Google"));
        Assert.assertFalse(title.contains("Yahoo"));


        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("google");
        driver.findElement(By.id("sblsbb")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.className("rg_l")).click();
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your code first which have you tried so far??

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `data-row` represent the row index and `data-ri` represent index of image where both are start with `0` index, you can simply find the exact image using `By.cssSelector()` by passing `data-ri` attribute index of the image, as in your case if you want second image, you should simple use as below :-

```
String imageIndex = "1";
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-ri = '" + imageIndex + "'] img"));
```

**Note**:- If you want other image just change `imageIndex` with which you want.

Comment: Can we use html tags in cssSelector? Edit: Oh I think you forgot to put a .click() after the findElement code.

Comment: @Nabz yes, you can use HTML tag in `cssSelector`, I didn't forgo to put click(), I just leaved it for you..:)

Comment: @Nabz you can use `image.click()` after successfully finding image..:)